# How to Insert documents to multiple collection in a single query using nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to insert documents into multiple collections by writing single query.

Let consider that I have two collections `person` and `address`. I want insert documents to both of this collections in single query. That is documents which are like **fname,lname** should be inserted inside `pesron` collection and documents which are like **city,state,country** should be inserted to `address` collections.

Is there any I can make this happen, If it is possible providing any answer with example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

mongoose doesn't provide this functionality & also node.js is synchronous... so you cant do 2 things at the same time. Is suggest leveraging [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
(async () => {
    const [createdPerson, createdAddress] = await Promise.all([
        person.create({
            fname: "name",
            lname: "lname"
        }),
        address.create({
            city: "city",
            state: "state",
            country: "country"
        })
    ]);
})();
```

Comment: do not consider my Schema. without async  is there any way

Comment: hello, please could you rephrase your question. I do not understand.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your updates, once again. Mongoose does not provide functionality to 'insert multiple collections in a single query'. you can use promise.all to partially achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible using MongoDb Transactions. I haven't tested yet, but there's a good example [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/transactions/#std-label-nodejs-transaction-core-api-example), and you can view it's settings [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/transactions/#transaction-settings). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use two dependent documents in two different collections so that if one insert fails other should fail also then you need to use MongoDB transactions API.

MongoDB transactions - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/
Mongoose reference to transactions - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html